# PostgreSQL: SELECT integers as DATE or TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a table where I have multiple integer columns: year, month and day. Unfortunately, while the three should have been grouped into one DATE column from the beginning, I am now stuck and now need to view it as such. Is there a function that can do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT makedate(year, month, day), othercolumn FROM tablename;
```

or

```
SELECT maketimestamp(year, month, day, 0, 0), othercolumn FROM tablename;
```

Comment: Out of interest, what DB are you used to having `makedate` and `maketimestamp` in? Docs links? I'd like to make sure the PostgreSQL versions are consistent.

Comment: I was not thinking of any specific DB. But I think MySQL has something similar to makedate (though it doesn't use months).

Comment: It does, but it takes a year and day of year [according to the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). [It looks like MySQL doesn't have anything exactly like you describe either](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960049/398670).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. In either case, I find it somewhat odd that these functions are not included.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can

```
SELECT format('%s-%s-%s', "year", "month", "day")::date
FROM ...
```

or use date maths:

```
SELECT DATE '0001-01-01'
    + ("year"-1) * INTERVAL '1' YEAR
    + ("month"-1) * INTERVAL '1' MONTH
    + ("day"-1) * INTERVAL '1' DAY
FROM ...
```

Frankly, it's surprising that PostgreSQL doesn't offer a date-constructor like you describe. It's something I should think about writing a patch for.

In fact, a quick look at the sources shows that there's an `int date2j(int y, int m, int d)` function at the C level already, in `src/backend/utils/adt/datetime.c`. It just needs to be exposed at the SQL level with a wrapper to convert to a `Datum`.

OK, [now here's a simple `makedate` extension](https://github.com/ringerc/scrapcode/tree/master/postgresql/makedate) that adds a single function implemented in C, named `makedate`. A pure-SQL version is also provided if you don't want to compile and install an extension. I'll submit the C function for the 9.4 commitfest; meanwhile that extension can be installed to provide a fast and simple date constructor:

```
regress=# SELECT makedate(2012,01,01);
  makedate  
------------
 2012-01-01
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PostgreSQL 9.4+

In [PostgreSQL 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html), a function was added to do just this

- [`make_date(year int, month int, day int)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant method, but this will give you a date.

```
select to_date(to_char(year * 10000 + month * 100 + day,'00000000'), 'yyyymmdd')
from   tablename;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT year * interval '1 year' + 
       month * interval '1 month' + 
       day * interval '1 day'
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: I think you'd have to add that to a date to get a date-type result -- it gives an interval, I think.