# MYSQL query for data between two dates,table does not have date column

Tags: mysql, date, date-difference

I have a table with four columns

```
 DAY |MONTH | YEAR | SUM_FILE_SIZE
----------------------------------------
```

How do i select sum_file_size from this table for a date range between 'day 1 month 7 year 2013'  to 'day 17 month 9 year 2014'?

I have tried this  query and it is giving incorrect data.

```
select day, month, year, sum_file_size
from bermuda_stat.fileandcite_daily
where day between 1 and 17 and month between 7 and 9 and year between 2013 and 2014
group by day, month, year
order by year, month, day.
```

How do i get all the sum_file_size between this two date range?

Please note that it is excluding all days other than whatever dates falls between 1 and 17 ,similarly it is excluding all months other than whatever months falls between 7 and 9?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create date from day, month, year fields in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960049/create-date-from-day-month-year-fields-in-mysql)

Comment: Why can't you just change the format to have a date column? This would be done so much easier.

Comment: already somebody has created this table.I can not help it.

Comment: Typing up answer now then. Just a moment.

Comment: I understand the difficulty of changing the table, but without a real DATE column, all solutions will cause a table-scan. This query cannot make use of an index, and performance will be bad. You should make the developer aware of this tradeoff.

Comment: This was a very old table created 9 years back .Thanks Bill.I will always keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this list of helpful [date and time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions. The first one you should notice(for this problem) is the MAKEDATE() function. If you give this a constant 1, it can be used to get the first day of a given year. So, for you example this would be:

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(year, 1) AS firstDayOfYear
FROM myTable
```

Now, you can use the ADDDATE() function to add the rest of your information. You can add the day like this:

```
SELECT ADDDATE(MAKEDATE(year, 1), INTERVAL (day - 1) DAY) AS dayAndYear
FROM myTable;
```

The reason I used (day-1) is because we already have a day of 1 from makedate. So 01-01 + 3 gives you 01-04 which is incorrect.

The month part works the same way, building on the last date.

```
SELECT ADDDATE(ADDDATE(MAKEDATE(year, 1), INTERVAL (day - 1) DAY), INTERVAL (month - 1) MONTH) AS fullDate
FROM myTable
```

Now, you can implement that into your where statement. Since you know the dates you want to restrict, you can treat those like dates. The final query looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(filesize)
FROM myTable
WHERE (ADDDATE(ADDDATE(MAKEDATE(year, 1), INTERVAL (day - 1) DAY), INTERVAL (month - 1) MONTH))
  BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-09-17';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26c35/1) example. I left each part in there, so you can see how the breakdown works step by step.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960049/create-date-from-day-month-year-fields-in-mysql) might also be helpful.

Comment: @Rudie is that sarcasm? I've never seen a function like that.

Comment: Not sarcasm, a wish. The function doesn't exist, that's why I said that. `MAKEDATE(year, days)` is a weird ass function.

Comment: @Rudie agreed. I thought for a moment there was a (year, month, day) function and that you were going to claim I overcomplicated this answer. We can only dream.

Answer (score 2):

I would just convert the dates to a number in the form YYYYMMDD and use that for the comparison:

```
where year*10000 + month*100 + day between 20130701 and 20140917
```

You could do something similar with strings, or even convert them to dates, but the numeric method should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me

```
SELECT `SUM_FILE_SIZE` 
FROM mytable
WHERE cast( concat(`year`,'-',`month`,'-',`day` ) AS DATE ) BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2014-09-17'
```

Comment: Subquery isn't necessary is it?

Comment: Yes we need a subquery if we don't want to display column 'mydate' in the result set. Because it is not the actual column in our table.

Comment: Couldn't you just `WHERE CAST(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day) AS DATE) BETWEEN x AND y`?