# Changing datetime value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

What I am trying to do, is to set beginning of time interval, if that is not correctly set into stored procedure. However, it somehow does not work very well..

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE intervals_generator (IN start DATETIME, IN ending DATETIME, IN intervalis INT)
BEGIN

    -- temp values
    DECLARE next_date DATETIME;

    -- result temp values
    DECLARE start_temp DATETIME;
    DECLARE ending_temp DATETIME;

    -- date formatting variables
    DECLARE year CHAR(20);
    DECLARE month CHAR(20);
    DECLARE day CHAR(20);

    DECLARE new_start CHAR(20);

    -- SET starting date if is incorrect  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %m %Y')
    SET year := DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y');
    SET month := DATE_FORMAT(start, '%c');
    SET day := DATE_FORMAT(start, '%e');

    IF intervalis = '1_day' THEN
        BEGIN
            SET new_start := year+' '+month+' '+day+' 00:00:00';
        END;
    ELSEIF intervalis = '1_month' THEN
        BEGIN
            SET new_start := year+' '+month+' 1 00:00:00';
        END;
    ELSEIF intervalis = '1_quarter' THEN
        BEGIN
            IF MONTH(start) IN (2, 3) THEN
                SET month := 1;
            ELSEIF MONTH(start) IN (5, 6) THEN
                SET month := 4;
            ELSEIF MONTH(start) IN (8, 9) THEN
                SET month := 7;
            ELSEIF MONTH(start) IN (11, 12) THEN
                SET month := 10;
            END IF;
            SET new_start := year+' '+month+' 1 00:00:00';
        END;
    ELSEIF intervalis = '1_year' THEN
        BEGIN
            SET new_start := year+' 1 1 00:00:00';
        END;
    END IF;
    SET start := STR_TO_DATE(new_start, '%Y %c %e %h:%i:%s');

    SELECT year, month, day, start;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS intervals_result;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I have tried many different formattings settings and functions, but the output is still wrong, like this:

```
mysql> CALL intervals_generator('2013-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:00:00', '1_year');
+------+-------+------+---------------------+
| year | month | day  | start               |
+------+-------+------+---------------------+
| 2013 | 2     | 1    | 2016-00-00 00:00:00 |
+------+-------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
```

I really dont understand why output is "2016-00-00" instead of "2013-01-01". year, month and day variables are defined as CHAR and also function that extracts them from datetime should be returning CHAR. And function STR_TO_DATE should also been taking CHAR format, so it is a mystery for me.

If anyone has some idea, please give me hint.

Comment: Function should return time intervals, 4 possible: days, months, quarters, years. And in first part of procedure (which I am talking about in this question) it should find beggining of first time interval. So for example IF I chose quarter intervals and enter beginning datetime as "2013-05-03", this code should correct my input into "2013-04-01", as that is real beginning of second quarter, in which my given start date fits into.
If I chose year interval, my function should change my input date into first january, of given year, if my input date is not first january.

Comment: Can't you use something simpler, like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22697/1 or http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22701/2

Comment: @lad2025 Those would make good answers. *hint hint*

Comment: @Schwern Posted as answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in [`DATE`s](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) instead of strings, you can make use of MySQL's date [functions and operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and make everything a whole lot simpler... but not too simple because this is MySQL.

The problem with MySQL and dates is its date functionality is a real mish-mash that sometimes works with `DATE`s, sometimes with strings, sometimes with integers, and is missing basic functionality. It lacks a simple function to set a piece of a date; there's no function to change the `MONTH` part of a `DATE` to February. There's not even a good way to make a date from the year, month and day, closest thing you get is [`MAKEDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate) which takes a year and the day of the year (*?!*). [Fortunately, `DATE`s in MySQL respond to math operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746923/14660) and it's better than messing with strings.

If you have, for example, `2013-02-12` and want `2013-02-01` you have to first make a new date with just the year using [`MAKEDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate), then add the month part.

```
-- 2013-01-01
SET new_date := MAKEDATE(YEAR(old_date), 1);

-- 2013-02-01
-- Since MONTH returns from 1 to 12, you need to take away one.
SET new_date := new_date + (INTERVAL MONTH(old_date) - 1) MONTH;
```

After chopping out all the unused variables, changing to date math, and using the [CASE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) instead of a big IF/ELSE chain, we get this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE intervals_generator (IN start_date DATE, IN intervals TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_start DATE;

    CASE intervals
        WHEN '1_day' THEN
            -- Nothing to do, DATE has already truncated the time portion.
            SET new_start := start_date;
        WHEN '1_month' THEN
            -- Set to the year and month of the start date
            SET new_start := MAKEDATE(YEAR(start_date), 1) + INTERVAL (MONTH(start_date) - 1) MONTH;
        WHEN '1_quarter' THEN
        BEGIN
            -- Set to the year and month of the start date
            SET new_start := MAKEDATE(YEAR(start_date), 1) + INTERVAL (MONTH(start_date) - 1) MONTH;
            -- Subtract the necessary months for the beginning of the quarter
            SET new_start := new_start - INTERVAL (MONTH(new_start) - 1) % 3 MONTH;
        END;
        WHEN '1_year' THEN
            -- Set the date to the first day of the year
            SET new_start := MAKEDATE(YEAR(start_date), 1);
    END CASE;

    SELECT new_start;
END//
```

[Try it out.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3ad0/1)

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not doing what you expect:

```
SET new_start := year+' '+month+' '+day+' 00:00:00';
```

In MySQL, the `+` operator does addition.  That's it, not concatenation.

I think you intend:

```
SET new_start := concat(year, ' ', month, ' ', day, ' 00:00:00');
```

I haven't looked at the rest of the logic to see if it makes sense, but this is one glaring problem.

Comment: Thanks for clearing me where the problem comes from. I am used to postgreSQL, just this one project I have to do in MySQL, so this is great help for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of slicing and building new date from parts(concatenating) which is error-prone  you can use built-in [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22697/1)**

```
SET @date = '2013-05-03 10:05:00';
SELECT CAST(@date AS DATETIME) AS Date,
   DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:00') AS Year_Allign,
   CASE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM @date)
      WHEN 1 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:00')
      WHEN 2 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-04-01 00:00:00')
      WHEN 3 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-07-01 00:00:00')
      WHEN 4 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-10-01 00:00:00')
      ELSE NULL END AS Quarter_Allign,
   DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AS Month_Allign,
   DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS Day_Allign;
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22701/2)**

```
SET @date = '2013-05-03 10:05:00';
SET @allign = '1_QUARTER';
SELECT
   CAST(@date AS DATETIME) AS Date,
   CASE @allign
     WHEN '1_YEAR' THEN  DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:00')
     WHEN '1_QUARTER' THEN  (CASE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM @date)
                              WHEN 1 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:00')
                              WHEN 2 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-04-01 00:00:00')
                              WHEN 3 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-07-01 00:00:00')
                              WHEN 4 THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-10-01 00:00:00')
                              ELSE NULL END)
     WHEN '1_MONTH' THEN DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
     WHEN '1_DAY' THEN  DATE_FORMAT(@date ,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
     ELSE NULL
     END AS Alligned;
```