# MySql fetch records date wise from day,month,separate columns

Tags: mysql, date

I have table named as **Subscription_stats** having columns as **day,monyh,year,total_payments**.And i have to fetch records datewise.The problem is i am having day,month,year separate columns so how can i fetch records.I am not only fetching data by filters i also wants all data datewise.

Sample input :

```
Day Month   Year    Total_payments
10  01      2008    10
10  01      2008    20
11  02      2008    10
10  03      2010    10
```

Output:

Datewise :

```
  date       total_payments
-----------------------------
10-01-2008   30
11-02-2008   10
10-03-2010   10
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create date from day, month, year fields in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960049/create-date-from-day-month-year-fields-in-mysql)

Comment: Don't have separate columns

Comment: This is not duplicate question. I want all count of total_payments according to date as i have mentioned in my sample input and output. please help me to solve the problem

Comment: @Eric, by adding where clause it is not working.
I have almost same table structure.

 `SELECT pay_id,  CONCAT(pay_year, '-', pay_month, '-01') FROM payment WHERE 1
 AND CONCAT(pay_year, '-', pay_month, '-01') >= '2018-04-01'
 AND CONCAT(pay_year, '-', pay_month, '-31') <= '2018-04-31'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(day, '-', month, '-', year) date, SUM(total_payments) total_payments
FROM Subscription_stats
GROUP BY year, month, day
ORDER BY year, month, day
```

This will order by Year first, then Month, then day, and will output a column with the concatenated date, and sum the total_payments together.

Comment: Eric thanks for giving answere but this does not gives right answere.Actually it returns only one row contains two columns. First column is date which is the first records date from table and second column is total payment which is total of all total_payments from table.

Comment: Like according to my above sample input it will give one row having two column (1) 10-01-2008 and second column (2) 50

Comment: Sorry, you have to add GROUP BY before the ORDER BY