# Get data based on year and month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some data : month_number (int), year(int).

I want to get data based on 2 years and 2 months

```
SELECT
  tt.year AS raw_annee,
  tt.month AS raw_mois,
  tt.product AS raw_produit,
  tt.quantity_product AS tonnes_prod,
  tt.quantity_n AS raw_tonnes_N,
  tt.quantity_p AS raw_tonnes_P,
  tt.quantity_k AS raw_tonnes_K
FROM test_test as tt    
  WHERE (tt.year >= 2014 AND tt.month_number >= 5)
  AND (tt.year <= 2018 AND tt.month_number <= 5)
  ORDER BY tt.year desc, tt.month_number desc;
```

But I get only data for month 'may' from 2014 to 2018, but the idea is to get data from may 2014 ---> may 2018

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Which dbms. MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh MySQL....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only want to compare months for first and last years:

```
  WHERE (tt.year > 2014 AND tt.year < 2018)
    or  (tt.year = 2014 AND tt.month_number >= 5)
    or  (tt.year = 2018 AND tt.month_number <= 5)
```

Alternatively:

```
WHERE (tt.year * 100 + tt.month_number >= 201405)
  AND (tt.year * 100 + tt.month_number <= 201805)
```

Or, not supported by MySQL:

```
WHERE (tt.year, tt.month_number) between (2014,5) and (2018,5)
```

Adapted to MySQL by Raymond Nijland:

```
WHERE (tt.year, tt.month_number) >= (2014,5) AND (tt.year, tt.month_number) <= (2018,5)
```

Comment: fast typing mate.

Comment: The last filter will result in a [error](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cWLHjmGtZe8Y29RKrFpN7k/4) like you expected. i wanted to try this because i never saw the syntax used before in (My)SQL,

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I removed the WHERE clause and found your query correct!

Comment: well i removed the comment because i was thinking `WHERE (tt.year, tt.month) >= (2014,5) AND (tt.year, tt.month) <= (2018,5)` was generating invalid results..Well it indeed [didn't](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cWLHjmGtZe8Y29RKrFpN7k/6) and i didn't validate the results before, i think i need caffeine badly..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the following:

```
SELECT
  tt.year AS raw_annee,
  tt.month AS raw_mois,
  tt.product AS raw_produit,
  tt.quantity_product AS tonnes_prod,
  tt.quantity_n AS raw_tonnes_N,
  tt.quantity_p AS raw_tonnes_P,
  tt.quantity_k AS raw_tonnes_K
FROM test_test as tt    
  WHERE (tt.year > 2014 AND tt.year < 2018) OR  (tt.year = 2014 AND tt.month_number >= 5) OR  (tt.year = 2018 AND tt.month_number <= 5)
  ORDER BY tt.year desc, tt.month_number desc;
```

Just an edit in your logic in your where statement

Answer (score 0):

Other way with building date :

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tt.year,'-',tt.month_number,'-',01), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Example :

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tt.year,'-',tt.month_number,'-',01), '%Y-%m-%d')  >= '01-05-2014' AND  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(tt.year,'-',tt.month_number,'-',01), '%Y-%m-%d') <= '01-05-2018'
```

[Create date from day, month, year fields in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960049/create-date-from-day-month-year-fields-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do the comparison as a date:

```
where date(concat_ws('-', tt.year, tt.month_number)) between '2014-05-01' and '2018-05-01
```

If you need to do date comparisons, then I would recommend that you store the values as dates.