# MySQL: inserting datetime.date(2023,6,22) into a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

I have an sql file containing, say,

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, datetime.date(2023, 2, 22));
```

How do I create a table that will accept this? More explicitly, in

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(ID INT NOT NULL, Date ???)) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

what should I put in place of '????'?

When I substitute `varchar(12)` for `????`,
I get the error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1630 (42000): FUNCTION datetime.date does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual.
```

Checking doesn't reveal any insights, at least for me.
What should I be doing?

Comment: Your question seem to be: "How to create a date when year, month and day are given".  That question has already answer here: [Create date from day, month, year fields in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960049/create-date-from-day-month-year-fields-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)` fails because there is no function `date` in the `datetime` schema/database. One *"dirty workaround"*, to avoid doing a mass string replace on your SQL file, is to create a `date` function in the `datetime` schema. MySQL will raise a `1585` warning, due to their being a native function with the same name, but it will allow you to create it. This is a lazy version as I have not done any validation on the inputs, but hopefully you get the idea:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA `datetime`;
USE `datetime`;

CREATE FUNCTION `datetime`.`date` (y SMALLINT UNSIGNED, m TINYINT UNSIGNED, d TINYINT UNSIGNED)
  RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', y, m, d));

SELECT datetime.date(2023, 2, 22);
```

A better option would be to modify your SQL file with `sed`:

```
sed -i -E "s/datetime.date\(([0-9]{4}), ([0-9]{1,2}), ([0-9]{1,2})\)/'\1-\2-\3'/" your_sql_file.sql
```

which will rewrite `your_sql_file.sql` from:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, datetime.date(2023, 2, 22));
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, datetime.date(2023, 3, 23));
```

to:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, '2023-2-22');
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, '2023-3-23');
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I shall try it both ways. I am not familiar with sed, though it looks to be  powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass a date in string format (ex. '2023-02-22'), notice the quotes since it should be a string. Also, the data type of the column should simply be a DATE.

Create table:
`CREATE TABLE mytable(ID INT NOT NULL, Date DATE) ENGINE=INNODB;`

Insert values:
`INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, '2023-02-22');`

Comment: The date value is not a string in my case but 'datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)' without the quotes. There are thousands of these in the sql file. I could, of course, modify the sql file and replace all datetime.date's with an equivalent string and my problem would be solved in a roundabout way. However, the file was given to me with datetime.date's, so I guess there must be a direct way, perhaps using functions? Any thoughts?

Comment: Does having the 'DATE' data type in place of '???' give the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that MySQL is interpreting `datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)` as a function call, which doesn't exist in MySQL, hence the error. This is because you used `datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)` inside your INSERT INTO statement, and it seems that the MySQL connector is treating it as a function rather than a date value.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  Date DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So ideally you should convert the date objects to the desired MySQL date format and then use that in your INSERT queries.

Comment: Thank you, Beulah. I can see what you are getting at. Unfortunately, the INSERT INTO....VALUES(1, datetime.date(2023, 2, 22)); isn't my construct. It is just an example of what is in a very large sql file, each row of which contains an INSERT clause with a datetime.date VALUE. Of course, I can search for the datetime.date in each line of the sql file and convert it to a string and then execute the INSERT commands on each line. Is there a way for MySQL to recognize the datetime.date user specified function?

Comment: Check if this works

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76798441/22308196

Answer (score -1):

Create the schema named datetime and switch to the datetime schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA datetime;
USE datetime;
```

Create the function `date` in the `datetime` schema:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION date(year_val INT, month_val INT, day_val INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE date_str VARCHAR(10);

    SET date_str = CONCAT(
        year_val,
        '-',
        LPAD(month_val, 2, '0'),
        '-',
        LPAD(day_val, 2, '0')
    );

    RETURN date_str;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

So the script to create the `mytable` table in the datetime schema would be:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

and the insert query would be:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Date) VALUES (1, datetime.date(2023, 2, 22));
```

Comment: When I would create this function, I would have it returned a `DATE`, and not a `VARCHAR(10)`, because it's illogical to return a varchar when you need a date.

Comment: Interesting. It worked the first time after creating the date function. It failed on subsequent times: 'Selected name conflicts with existing function 'date'.